# How to add Geopoint, timestamp and reference to a document in Firestore trough Flutter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

It is fairly straightforward hot to set basic types inside Firestore.

But I cannot find how to construct Geopoint, Timestamp and another document reference with flutter Firestore plugin.

What do you assing inside data that you set to the coollection `Map<String,dynamic>` for each object?

Any help or examples?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I created manually an object on the server and got it inside my flutter app.
[image]

For TimeStamp you can pass `DateTime` object directly from dart.

For Geopoint there is GeoPoint object inside Firestore plugin.

```
new GeoPoint(longitude: 3.4, latitude: 4.5) })
```

For another document reference, you would pass `DocumentReference` that you retrieved as a value to the data object.

Answer (score 5):

To create or update geopoint in firebase you can use the object GeoPoint(Latitude, Longitude) directly, this example from [official documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> updateUser() {
  return users
    .doc('ABC123')
    .update({'info.address.location': GeoPoint(53.483959, -2.244644)})
    .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of flutter a GeoPoint is created without named parameters.

```
GeoPoint(0, 0);
```

first argument => latitude

second argument => longitude