# How to upload a geopoint to the firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I have to save two coordinates to my firestore, but I have to save them as `geopoint` type in firestore. I have the data (`LatLng`) from a gmaps and don't know how to upload them as a `geopoint`. I also tried to upload the list without the `.toString()` after the `companyLocation`, but then the whole function doesn't work. When I run the code I have at the moment, the data is uploaded like `'LatLng(47.79806357324117, 13.031338155269623)'` as a string which is because of the `.toString()` I'm using.

I tried the following:

I reated a new `LatLng`:

```
LatLng companyLocation;
```

I have the function for getting the data by tapping on the map:

```
List<Marker> myMarker = [];

  _onTap(LatLng tappedPoint) {
    setState(() {
      myMarker = [];
      myMarker.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(tappedPoint.toString()),
          position: tappedPoint,
        ),
      );
      companyLocation = tappedPoint;
      print(companyLocation);
    });
  }
```

And then I tried to upload a list with the data to my firestore:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'name': nameController.text,
      'location': companyLocation.toString(),
    };
```

I tried the code mentioned in the comments below, but I get an error (the GeoPoint is red underlined) why do I get this?

This is a screenshot[image]

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573854/how-to-add-geopoint-timestamp-and-reference-to-a-document-in-firestore-trough-f

Comment: But when I try this code: new GeoPoint (latitude: companyLocation.latitude, longitude: companyLocation.longitude); then the GeoPoint is red underlined

Comment: This might help [flutter-realtime-geolocation-firebase/](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-realtime-geolocation-firebase/)

Comment: What does the red line error message tell you?Have you got this line at the top of your code: import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';?

Comment: I edit the question with a screenshot for showing what is red underkined

Comment: I use VSCode, not Android Studio. I would assume AS does the same thing if you can find the right setting amongst the thousands but in VSCode if you hover over the red line error, it tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting? also, check this post, situation is similar, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603691/how-to-save-geopoint-in-firebase-cloud-firestore